# How to convert list of tuple to an array

Tags: python, numpy

```
new = zero(rows_A,cols_B)
for i in range(rows_A):
    for j in range(cols_B):     
        new[i][j] += np.sum(A[i] * B[:,j])
```

If I'm using this form of array `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]` in `B`
it is giving me an error

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

but if I'm using same array `B`, in place of `A`, it's working well.

I am getting this type of return array

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]
```

so i want to convert it into this form

```
[[0 0 0]
[0 1 0]
[0 2 1]]
```

Comment: Please show what `rows_A`, `cols_B`, `A`, and `B` are.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.asarray` will do that.

```
import numpy as np

B = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]])
```

This produces

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1]])
```

which can be indexed with `[:, j]`.

Also, it looks like you're trying to do a matrix product. You can do the same thing with just one line of code using `np.dot`:

```
new = np.dot(A, B)
```

Comment: i can do like that but my prof. want me to code it and optimize the code.
thnks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `B` is a list.  You can't index it as `B[:,i]` -- Which is implcitly passed to `__getitem__` as `(slice(None,None,None),i)` -- i.e. a tuple.

You could convert `B` to a numpy array first (`B = np.array(B)`) and then go from there ...